# Split a string by comma except when in bracket and except when directly before and/or after the comma is a dash "-"?

Tags: python, regex, split

just trying to figure out how to plit a string by comma except when in bracket AND except when directly before and/or after the comma is a dash. I have already found some good solutions for how to deal with the bracket problem but I do not have any clue how to extend this to my problem.

Here is an example:

```
example_string = 'A-la-carte-Küche, Garnieren (Speisen, Getränke), Kosten-, Leistungsrechnung, Berufsausbildung, -fortbildung'
aim = ['A-la-carte-Küche', 'Garnieren (Speisen, Getränke)', 'Kosten-, Leistungsrechnung', 'Berufsausbildung, -fortbildung']
```

So far, I have managed to do the following:

```
>>> re.split(r',\s*(?![^()]*\))', example_string)
>>> out: ['A-la-carte-Küche', 'Garnieren (Speisen, Getränke)', 'Kosten-', 'Leistungsrechnung', 'Berufsausbildung', '-fortbildung']
```

Note the difference between aim and out for the  terms 'Kosten-, Leistungsrechnung' and 'Berufsausbildung, -fortbildung'.
Would be glad if someone could help me out such that the output looks like aim.

Thanks in advance!
Alex

Comment: Possibly not applicable, but this is a case where the *producer* should produce something more amenable to parsing.

Answer (score 2):

If you can make use of the python [regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), you could do:

```
\([^()]*\)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<!-)\s*,\s*(?!,)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\([^()]*\)` Match from an opening till closing parenthesis
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` Skip the match
- `|` Or
- `(?<!-)\s*,\s*(?!,)` Match a comma between optional whitespace chars to split on

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KMztm9/1)

```
import regex

example_string = 'A-la-carte-Küche, Garnieren (Speisen, Getränke), Kosten-, Leistungsrechnung, Berufsausbildung, -fortbildung'
print(regex.split(r"\([^()]*\)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<!-)\s*,\s*(?!,)", example_string))
```

Output

```
['A-la-carte-Küche', ' Garnieren (Speisen, Getränke)', ' Kosten-, Leistungsrechnung', ' Berufsausbildung', ' -fortbildung']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
re.split(r'(?<!-),(?!\s*-)\s*(?![^()]*\))', example_string)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/o6fVjL). *Details*:

- `(?<!-)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `-` char immediately to the left of the current location
- `,` - a comma
- `(?!\s*-)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `-` char immediately to the right of the current location
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?![^()]*\))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are zero or more chars other than `)` and `(` and then a `)` char immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9OYYbJ/1), too.